# Error in changing theme in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having a problem in my simple application. I am following the tutorial from the android website. There's a part that they use Holo Light as a theme. But my problem is I am getting an error when I choose this theme. I also looked at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity) and tried some of the approaches but still I am getting the same error.

Here's my errors:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with the design library.
>         at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
>         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>         at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
>         at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
>         at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
>         at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
>         at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
>         at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>         at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>         at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>         at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>         at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>         at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>         at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>         at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>         at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>         at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>         at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>         at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here's my files:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flax.myfirstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.flax.myfirstapp.MyActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
package com.flax.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
......
```

Can you help me with this? I am extremely new in Android Development. I am stuck since yesterday with this errors. :(

Here's the image of my file structure and also the error:

[image]

Comment: Android studio's version?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue:

[image]

Since your project seems to be a new project with the default configuration, and you already have:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And also:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

In your `Manifest`, it seems to be a bug or problem with **Android Studio** and i hope it will fixed soon.

But with our codes, everything is okay, no problem, i will report this to **Google**.

And onething more, because that `layout` is coming from the `main_layout.xml` with this line:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

It should be the reason, but, i've tried that and same issue.

But, for now, if you need to design that `Layout`, you may want to change the `Theme` for your `Android Studio's Preview` to a `Light` with `DarkActionbar`.

Or change the theme to `AppTheme`, like this:

[image]

It should work then.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can only preview using the `AppTheme` only. Whenever I tried different theme I always got those errrors.

Comment: Yes, because it's a `Layout` and it's coming from `main_content.xml` and it doesn't have any styles, we need to add an inheritance like this case from the main layout

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Maybe I should stop studying for now until there is a fix in this error. If you found some solution with this one please send me the link. Thanks. :)

Comment: Ill try to look for some solutions too. :)

Comment: There is also a canary channel for newest version of android studio, i think they will fix these problems in the newest version, see: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary the latest preview is almost finished, they will realased the new version soon, you can use that `AppTheme` for now or downloading the latest version from canary channel.goodluck :)

Comment: Is it still fine to continue my study even if this error still existing?

Comment: Well, these things are normal and that's because it's just a layout which comes from main layout, you could even use that layout in the main layout without these errors:) by removing this line and designing your own layout(not recommended, and no need to stop:) ) **:** `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and set it

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Perfect Answer #Eagle eye

Comment: Thanks, I modified my manifest and style. But I still get the same errors. I also tried to change the API types. Currently I am using API 23.

Comment: Where you changed this ? `style.xml` under `values` or `values-v23` ?

Comment: I dont have `values-23` but I  have 2 styles. Under styles.xml there are `styles.xml` and `styles.xml(2)` I will attach the image of my file structure.

Comment: do changes at both placses

Comment: I added the screenshot of my file project. Ok I will modify both.

Comment: By the way do I need to modify also the path in the parent in styles.xml? I modified it like this `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: @MD - this is the default configuration for a new project on Android studio, doesn't make any sense.